# Dictionary in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dictionary

How can I build an English-English Dictionary for iPhone/iPad ? Any tutorial ?

iOS Beginner

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a generic English dictionary, [Lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com/) is a good offline library based on WordNet definitions.

Answer (score 1):

By using the NSDicitionary you can able to do this..Just you store all the words and its meanings in a plist. For the words you can assign it as keys and for the meaning of that word you assing it as values.... [NSDicitionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: how about performance if the list of words is in rage of 150,000 ?